# QGIS - automated extraction of route section

Tags: qgis, extract

I want to extract a section of a route. My base data are route polylines and kilometer points with kilometerinformation along the route. Suppose I want to automatically create the route segment from kilometer 103 to 108 as a separate line-layer. What approach can I take?
[image: route exapmle]

Comment: Are the points exactly above the vertices of the line or above the segment?

Comment: This is a linear referencing task, have a look at the LRS plugin that will handle this

Comment: hello Mayo. The points are above the segment...
Hello J.R. Thanks for the hint with LRS. I have to look into that, seems it's not as self-explaining, as I hoped...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be achieved using the *Geometry by Expression* tool. Run this expression on your `line` layer. Make sure to select *Line* as the output geometry type:

###### Tool parameters

[image]

###### Expression

```
-- make variables of the start and end points (not necessary but is more convenient when changing the values)
with_variable('start', geometry(get_feature('points', 'kilometer', 103)),  -- change the 'points' layer name here to suit your project
    with_variable('end', geometry(get_feature('points', 'kilometer', 108)),  -- change the 'points' layer name here to suit your project
        
        -- substring the current line using the distances calculated below
        line_substring(
            $geometry,
            
            -- find the distance along the line of the closest point on the line to the start point
            line_locate_point(
                $geometry,
                closest_point(
                    $geometry,
                    @start
                )
            ),

            -- find the distance along the line of the closest point on the line to the end point
            line_locate_point(
                $geometry,
                closest_point(
                    $geometry,
                    @end
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

###### Result

[image]

By using the additional `closest_point` function (rather than inputting the `@start` and `@end` points directly into the `line_locate_point` functions) the expression handles situations where your kilometer marker points are not exactly on your line features.